# How can I check if a is file inside of a directory (with multiple other directories)? with the OS module

Tags: python, operating-system

Presume I have a directory structure like so

```
Directory of C:\treeofbkup

10/17/2012  01:59 PM    <DIR>          .
10/17/2012  01:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/17/2012  01:59 PM             7,209 index
10/17/2012  01:59 PM    <DIR>          objects
               1 File(s)          7,209 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  912,672,129,024 bytes free
```

With files contained in the folder `objects`.

My question is there a way to check if a file regardless of name of `objects` (say I do not have knowledge of that folders name)? without writting a for loop to manually walk through the path of my directory structure?

```
def search(path, file):
    for  (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            if file == f:
                return True #hey look here is my file
    return False #oops couldnt find your file sorry
```

The solution I'm after is something like `directory_set = set()` and `if directory_set.contains(path)`. I'm sorry if this question is confusing to some

Comment: In terms of computation time its quite inefficient (depending on how many files I need to search over, my search space is about N number of files squared)

Comment: There's not really a way to do this, unless you can hook into an OS-specific indexing tool like `locate` (Unix) or `mdfind` (OS X), and even then there's no guarantee the index will be up to date or even exist at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. You'll have to walk the tree at least once, and then you could store a lookup table of filenames to possible directories (either pickled, or a sqlite3 dbase for instance) if you wanted to re-use it often.